# Azure Service Fabric:How to pass data to guest executable at run time?

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, azure-cloud-services

I have a stateless service that spin up a new guest executable on demand.I need to pass some data at service creation time to guest executable.
How can i do that??

Comment: Can the data be stored in a common location so the guest executable can grab it when run?  Just thinking out loud: I'm new to SF and not sure if what you're asking is possible.  What does "on demand" mean -- how is the executable triggered?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass command line arguments using `Arguments`
and (configuration) files to the executable, by setting `WorkingFolder` in the service manifest.

```
<EntryPoint>
   <ExeHost>
      <Program>node.exe</Program>
      <Arguments>bin/www</Arguments>
      <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
   </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

Comment: But spinner service get data from user and need to pass that data so entrypoint can't be used there. Let say user give name of service and asks us to create guest service with that name

Comment: in that case, you can use `FabricClient.ServiceManager` to create dynamic instances of your service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.createserviceasync?view=azure-dotnet#System_Fabric_FabricClient_ServiceManagementClient_CreateServiceAsync_System_Fabric_Description_ServiceDescription_ and pass binary info the ctor as `InitializationData`

Comment: yp but it(InitializationData) is not supported in guest executable :(